# Дублирование в базе данных Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Привет. Возникла проблема.

Есть пост

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PostName { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

с комментариями:

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserComment { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

Использую EntityFramework CodeFirst

```
public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
public DbSet<Comment> Coments { get; set; }
```

добавляю посты:

```
var b1 = new Post();
b1.PostName = "First";
var b2 = new Post();
b2.PostName = "Second";
var b3 = new Post();
b3.PostName = "Third";

using (var context = new testDb())
{
    context.Posts.Add(b1);
    context.Posts.Add(b2);
    context.Posts.Add(b3);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

т.к у меня работа идет с двумя репозиториями в проекте которые по отдельности работают с 2 сущностями(Post и Comment ) я использую 2 using.
Например я хочу добавить новый комментарий:

Нахожу пост в который нужно добавить комментарий

```
var b1 = new Post();
using (var context = new testDb())
{
    b1 = context.Posts.Where(x => x.PostName == "First").FirstOrDefault();                                                            
}
```

Добавляю комментарий:

```
Comment c1 = new Comment();
c1.Post = b1;
c1.UserComment = "test comment first";
using (var context = new testDb())
{
    context.Coments.Add(c1);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Проблема в том что в базе дублируется Post c каждым комментарием.
В чем причина дублирования. Я просто хочу добавить комментарий используя несколько using.

Посты до добавления комментария http://prntscr.com/gyttij

Посты после добавления комментария http://prntscr.com/gytun5

Я могу сохранить используя пост который я вытянул из базы:
post.Comments.Add(comment);

но в каждом репозитории я работаю с отдельной сущностью и поэтому нужно добавлять все в comments.add(comment).

Помогите с решением этой проблемы

Comment: А зачем вы контекст 2 раза создаете? Естественно во второй раз пост контексту неизвестен и он его добавляет, либо работайте в одном контексте, либо прикрепляйте пост ко второму контексту

Comment: так я его и прикрепляю c1.Post = b1;  контексты у меня в разных репозиториях. Из одного репозитория я вытягиваю пост...создаю комментарий...добавляю ссылку  к какому посту идет добавление и сохраняю во втором репозитории.

Comment: К контексту, я имею ввиду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы работаете в разных контекстах, поэтому второму контексту пост из первого неизвестен, нужно прикрепить его вручную:

```
context.Posts.Attach(b1);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо Андрей. К сожалению рейтинг пока не могу добавлять. Я так понял Attach добавляет ссылку на нужный пост.

Comment: Роман, если Вам дан правильный ответ - отметьте его как верный (зеленой галочкой слева).

Comment: @РоманПетров, вы можете проголосовать за ответ и принять его, слева от ответа стрелки и галочка. Естественно, после того как проверите его и убедитесь что он вам подходит.

Comment: @Zufir, для того, чтобы пользователь увидел ваше сообщение нужно добавлять символ @ и ник этого пользователя, тогда он получит уведомление